# Transition effect in Accordion Created by me

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a accordion by `jquery` and `css`. Everything is ok but i can't use transition for slowly collapsed. Because when it collapsed, it is collapsing very fast and when close, it is closing very fast. I can't using transition.

My [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/maamunrcd/e98d9t3g/)

Here is my code is......

HTML--

```
<div class="accordiam">
            <div class="child_bg">
                <h2 class="title_headig"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</a></h2>
                <div class="accordiam_body">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
                        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
                        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                        reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="child_bg">
                <h2 class="title_headig"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</a></h2>
                <div class="accordiam_body active">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
                        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
                        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                        reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="child_bg">
                <h2 class="title_headig"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</a></h2>
                <div class="accordiam_body">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
                        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
                        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                        reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

css--

```
.accordiam
            {
                width:800px;
            }
            h2
            {
                margin:0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .child_bg
            {margin: 1px 0 0 0;}
            .title_headig a
            {
                padding:8px 20px;
                background:#999900;
                font-size: 18px;
                font-family: monospace;
                text-decoration: none;
                color:#fff;
                z-index: 500;
                display: block;
                position: relative;
                margin:0;
                line-height: 28px;
            }
            .accordiam_body
            {
                width:96.6%;
                background:#fff;
                line-height: 25px;
                height:auto;
                border: 1px solid #999;
                padding:0px 0px 0px 25px;
                transition:all .5s;
                display:none;
            }

             .accordiam_body.active
            {
                display: block;
            }
```

jquery--

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".title_headig a").click(function(){
                    $(".accordiam_body").hide();
                    $(this).parent().parent().children(".accordiam_body").slideToggle(000);
                });
            })
```

Comment: You are passing 000 to .slideToggle()  - is that intentional? Try .slideToggle(1000)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make the toggle effect "slow", but you needt to delete your transition inside the css

```
slideToggle("slow");
```

The documentation for slideToggle : http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

https://jsfiddle.net/e98d9t3g/1/

Comment: It's OK but hardly pushing when collapsed out.